# HTML Email Not Showing in Entirety on Mac native mail client

Tags: html, macos, email, html-email

I'm working on an HTML email project. The email renders fine when viewing from Google's Inbox and Gmail on both Desktop and Mobile. However, the email just seems to get cut off toward the end when viewing on the Mac's native mail client. The strange this is the same exact email can be viewed in entirety on the Mail iOS App. Is this a known problem? Is there like a cut-off point for HTML email on Mac clients?

Comment: can you post the html you are using?

Comment: Please provide the html code, it can be some tags that the client dosnt like. When you say native, do you mean the program "mail"?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem (OS X 10.11.4) and it does not appear to be a problem with the HTML formatting (forgetting to close tags, etc). Nor is the messages cut off after a specific number of characters. However, it does always cut off the same number of characters (14) from the end, even though the messages have different lengths. When the final line is `--ContainerMixedBoundary--` (specifying the end of the attachment container), it will cut it off to `--ContainerM`, botching the rendering of the entire message. In my case, all the messages have the same basic format, always including a bin-hexed image attachment and ending with the same "ContainerMixedBoundary" marker. Some get cut off, some do not (about 1 out of every 7-10 overall, but it's not consistent).

For reference, here's the end of message 1, which renders fine:

`1UgHEW0DWGjZ5WVCBVVJrX2yY+mOSsHbgOig1698otDISqrz4j4u43PfGyrCV8t6tIKtRdu5xq+X
tT5hCvzYEEffk19UhXhEYYKOQANKg/qyuNuGDMACenc74FYivlvUiORTbpsanFB5cvBt1Phku4US
nVj1p9oDKXmu5XkoO1d2+jFWNxeXbj/d3wLSqkUJwUuhrH0JJ7kjt9GHDxXBcFTxjO++/wBwy6Sg
cvA7gCpNO2BX/9k=
--HTMLWrapperRelatedBoundary--
--ContainerMixedBoundary--`

And here's the end of message 2, which is cut off and does not render fine in Apple Mail OS X, but does render fine everywhere else (iOS Mail, GMail, Yahoo Mail):

`tO7UyCRgZG5A7ivUfLH+lGifCSyjqTWuJTSVKyOOJQkIwBIIP82KMvJhwcqWXqOnTocKqFTErKuy
v1H2jXHxKoUFlCkDeTfv4ZioRub9EoOZ8fHGpIXl+BwYq0ZCPxGKEQsUbEMG3XoO1R0ribRvI1W2
oe3fFjIvpcUCq1epAqcTEdKjbiDv9OKVORD6gWQhx4U6D3wk81qQsCnoCaEeFBkgoqbNUsR+Hhkf
8zrVYDv1Ox6YqGOqMUUZQXFVGBk2oxRRlKMVUYpt/9k=
--HTMLWrapperRelatedBoundary--
--ContainerM`

Again, these messages all share the same basic format and are generated by the same code, with the same tags and boundaries, the only difference is the content text between tags, and the image attachment data.

In fact, the problem appears in the Sent messages in Apple Mail OS X (which was not sent from Apple Mail, but through Gmail via code), but *the same message*, when received elsewhere, is fine. So the cut-off appears to be happening internally in Apple Mail and is not a problem with the message itself.